# When will span of vectors plus a constant form a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For set $W$ defined as:
[image]

$W$ is not a vector space because if $d = 0$ then $2d + 1 \neq 0$ so $0$ is not in $W$.

Note that the set above can be rewrited as linear combinations of vectors plus a constant vector:
$\{(0,0,1,0) + b(1, 2, 0, 0)+ d(-5,0,2,1) |\ b, d\ real \}$

The question can be generalized as:

If $W$ is the set of linear combinations of a set of vectors $\{v_1,...v_n \}$ plus a vector $v_0$ (all vectors are from $\mathbb{R}^m$), i.e.
$W=\{v_0+c_1v_1+c_2v_2+...+c_nv_n|\ v_0\neq 0\ ,\ c_i \text{ is any real scalar}\}$, under what conditions of $\{v_1,...v_n \}$ and $v_0$ will $W$ be a vector space?

$W$ can be a vector space though. For example, when $W = \{x+1|\ x \in \mathbb{R} \}$, $W = \mathbb{R}$ and $W$ is a vector space.

Comment: What do you mean by $c_0 + c_1v_1+\cdots$? $c_0$ is a scalar, but the rest of the terms are vectors, so the expression doesn't make sense. Do you mean to take $v_{j=1,\dots,n}$ as the standard basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and then ask when $c_0(v_1 + v_2 + \cdots + c_n) + c_1v_1+\cdots+c_nv_n$ is a vector space?

Comment: Or, are you assuming more general things about the $v_j$'s.  What are you assuming about the $v_j$'s?  Are they linearly independent? Do they form a basis? Etc. In your characterization, is $c_0$ actually supposed to be some fixed *vector*?  Please edit your post to include these clarifications!

Comment: @march I edit the question. Hope that will be clear.

Comment: Then I believe your question has already been answered below!

Answer (score 2):

Let $V$ be a vector space, $W\subseteq V$ a subspace and $v\in V$. Then $v+W$ is a subspace of $V$ iff $v\in W$.

Comment: I can understand if $v \in W$ then $v + W$ is a subspace. But how to prove that $v+W$ is a subspace then $v \in W$?

Comment: ...................................................

Comment: @hagen . if $v\neq 0$. Then it is also required that $W$ is not the trivial subspace . In that case $v+W=\{v\}$ is not a subspace.

Answer (score 0):

To your question in the comments. I take that $v\neq 0$ . Otherwise $v+W=W$.

Also $W$ must be a non trivial subspace for $v+W$ to be a subspace when $v\in W$. Othwewise the singleton set $\{v\}$ is not a subspace as $0\notin \{v\}$

Let $v+W$ is a subspace.

Then as $W$ is a subspace, $0\in W$.

So $v+0=v \in v+W$. Also let $v+w\in v+W$ for some $w\in W, w\neq 0$.

Then $v+w - v= w \in v+W$ as $v+W$ is a subspace.

Then $w\in v+W \implies w= v+w'$ for some $w' \in W$.

This means $w-w' = v \in W$.

So to sum it up. For a subspace $W$. $v+W$ is a subspace if $v=0$ or when $W$ is a nontrivial subspace and $v\in W$ .